# Forms authentication keeps redirecting back to loginUrl

Tags: c#, reporting-services, forms-authentication

I'm trying to set up FormsAuthentication in .Net App. It happens to be an SSRS authentication Extension but for the purpose of this question that shouldn't matter.

Logon flow:

1. Application redirects to `logon.aspx` when website is opened.
2. `Logon.aspx` redirects to auth site to authenticate (IDP).
3. Auth site redirects back to `Logon.aspx`.
4. `Logon.aspx` sets Forms authentication cookie.
5. `Logon.aspx` redirects to home page -> here's where it goes wrong, it redirects back to Logon.aspx.

Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" name="sqlAuthCookie" protection="All" path="/" timeout="180" enableCrossAppRedirects="true">
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="false" />
```

I tried a two ways to authenticate via forms:

```
            // Doesn't redirect
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, createPersistentCookie: true);

            // Set's cookie in response then redirects but comes back
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, createPersistentCookie: true);
            string returnUrl = "/ReportServer";
            Response.Redirect(returnUrl, false);
```

I don't know if it's a setting I missed or maybe the auth cookie is lost somewhere; when it redirects back to Logon.aspx the auth cookie is gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark really - it looks to me like you're missing some logic. I can recommend at least one troubleshooting task:

Ensure that forms authentication is set to use cookies ([read more](https://www.tenable.com/audits/items/CIS_v1.1.1_MS_IIS_10_Level_2.audit:4e8239f6013f9fae16d25eb3809945ae))

> 1. Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level where Forms Authentication is enabled
> 2. In Features View, double-click Authentication
> 3. On the Authentication page, select Forms Authentication
> 4. In the Actions pane, click Edit
> 5. In the Cookie settings section, select Use cookies from the Mode dropdown

Comment: Thanks @Tim. I enabled it now (<forms cookieless="UseCookies"...>) however the same issue persists.